# Why my tooltip cannot shown when I hover over layer in leaflet.js?

Tags: leaflet, javascript, tooltip

I want to use tooltip on my polyline to show its features and I use this code:

```
var boroughs = L.geoJson(null, {
  style: function (feature) {
    return {
      color: "black",
      fill: false,
      opacity: 1,
    };
  },
  onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
    layer.bindTooltip(feature.properties.KECAMATAN, {
      sticky: true
    });
    boroughSearch.push({
        name: layer.feature.properties.KECAMATAN,
        source: "Boroughs",
        id: layer.feature.properties.KODEKEC,
        bounds: layer.getBounds()
      });
    }
});
$.getJSON("data/kec.geojson", function (data) {
  boroughs.addData(data);
});
```

and I got a message in the console that said:

> TypeError: layer.bindTooltip is not a function

I don't know what's wrong with it, and I followed step by leaflet docs.

Comment: What version of Leaflet are you using?

Answer (score 1):

It might be because you are initiating an empty geojson layer. The following code is from this [Example](http://lyzidiamond.com/posts/external-geojson-and-leaflet-the-other-way) for creating an Ajax geojson layer:

```
  $.getJSON("./cupcakes/cupcakes.json",
       function(data) { 
         var geojson = L.geoJson(data,
            { 
                onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {           
                   layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.name);
                }
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

According [to the latest Leaflet documentation (1.3.4)](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.4.html#geojson) you would bind the Tooltip *after* you have constructed the `L.geoJson` object:

```js
L.geoJSON(data, {
  [...]
}).bindTooltip(function (layer) { 
  return layer.feature.properties.KECAMATAN 
});
```